# sqlsrv error while connecting to mssql server 2008 on windows 2003 server

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlsrv

I am getting following error while connecting mssql server 2008 using sqlsrv on windows 2003 server using `sqlsrv_connect` in PHP. Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client is already installed. Webserver running on IIS 6.0

Here's php.ini contents

=======================

```
[PHP_SQLSRV]
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll
[PHP_PDO_SQLSRV]
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc6.dll
php_pdo_sqlite.dll
```

=======================

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => IMSSP
            [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP
            [1] => -49
            [code] => -49
            [2] => This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712
            [message] => This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => IM002
            [SQLSTATE] => IM002
            [1] => 0
            [code] => 0
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to try,

first to check if the Native driver has the right version - 
is your server really a 32bit Version and not 84bit?

The other thing is, to check if the extensions are actually loaded.

To check that, create a file like "phpinfo.php" and put it in you folder for .htdocs.

```
<?php

// show phpinfo file
phpinfo();

?>
```

The easy way is to search for it in the phpinfo-Page with Ctrl+F  and "extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll"

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to this site: [Microsoft download site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065).
2. Scroll to `(+) Install Instructions` section, and click it.
3. Inside this section scroll to: `Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Native Client`.
4. You will see two links there: install one of them (up to your system 32 or 64)

> X86 Package (sqlncli.msi) [X86 direct link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239647&clcid=0x409)
>
> X64 Package (sqlncli.msi) its direct link in comment

Comment: [X64 Package direct link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239648&clcid=0x409)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you install Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. 
Follow [PHP requirement](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.requirements.php)